# differential drive + ros_control to move a 2 wheeled base of a robot?

Tags: ros, differential-drive, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, I am very new to ROS.
I would like to perform a simple task of moving the base of my robot. The package that I want to use to move my Robot's base (consists of 2 wheels) is as simple as this - http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller?distro=lunar. Can someone detail me about how to use this package and the hardware interface to a TI DSP controller which in turn drives the motor of my robot's wheels.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264574/differential-drive-+-ros_control-to-move-a-2-wheeled-base-of-a-robot?/) by [kiranmayee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30875/kiranmayee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-06-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-06-26**:
You have multiple problems, my suggestion: First research how to talk to your DSP, this is not a ROS problem and I suggest to ask at a DSP/Embedded board for a solution. If you have that next do all the ros tutorials then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I have to expand my comment a little, you are basically asking two questions:

- How to control your hardware

As I said in the comment this is not a ROS specific problem. You better write a driver that talks to your hardware first and then later convert it into a ROS node.

- How to use diff drive controller.

Diff drive controller and ros control are not packages I would give to a ros beginner to setup. While they are probably the right software to solve your problem they won't help you in understanding basic ros concepts. Thats what the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) are there for. Next I suggest to do the [navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials) on a simulated robot. Just to understand how the navigation stack works and what these odom/cmd_vel messages are.

Finally for ros control see this [roscon 2014 video](https://vimeo.com/107507546).

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kiranmayee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30875/kiranmayee/) on 2017-06-26**:
Thank you. Will check out the navigation tutorials and get back.